What was Moshe originally going to do with the East Bank land
Before Reuven and Gad asked for the land, what was Moshe planning on doing with it? They had this massive chunk of land and were they just going to abandon it?

According to the Ramban (Bamidbar 21:21), exactly that, leave it empty.

The answer is accepted, but it is counterintuitive, because the neiboring Ammon, Moav, Edom, and Midian could easily claim the unpopulated land.

Let them. The Ramban says Moshe knew the Jews were only getting 7 out of 10 so let these be the ones they're not getting. Midyan is actually a proof this way. The Jews seemingly wiped them all out, burnt their cities yet didn't take their land

Could you expand on this point in your answer, please? Thank you.

i dont think that was part of q. if op asked "if so why" then ill add
